# Text not displaying in WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I almost perfected my Combobox, its working 98%. The only thing missing is the highlighted color on an item. The moment I set this I get the desired highlighted color, but it displays no text. When I comment the highlight part out it works 100%, only the highlightcolor is wrong. Can someone see what is wrong.

This is my complete xaml:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxNormalBorderBrush" Color="#B9B9B9" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush" Color="#E1E1E1" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#eee" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDisabledBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton"         x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Border"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBorderBrush}" 
          CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1, 1, 1, 1" 
          Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="1, 1, 1, 1" BorderBrush="#444" Name="ButtonBorder"
          CornerRadius="0, 0, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 0" 
          Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Path Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" 
        Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="#444"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="#E5F1FB"/>
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#E5F1FB"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#0078D7"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="#CCE4F7"/>
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#CCE4F7"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#3176AF"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#999"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Grid.Column="2"
            ClickMode="Press" Focusable="False"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}"/>

                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" Margin="5, 3, 23, 3" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"                              
                          Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" 
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"/>
                    <TextBox Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Margin="3, 3, 23, 3"                     
                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                 Visibility="Hidden" Background="Transparent"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Focusable="True" >
                        <TextBox.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox" >
                                <Border Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </TextBox.Template>
                    </TextBox>
                    <!-- Popup showing items -->
                    <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom"
               Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True"
               IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}"
               PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth}"
                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border Name="DropDownBorder" Background="White" Margin="0, 1, 0, 0"
                    CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                    BorderBrush="#0078D7"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.MinHeight" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>               
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Resulting this (text in list missing):
[image]

Onece you comment out the last setter (HighlightColor), this piece:

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Resulting this (Text there, but highligtcolor wrong):
[image]
Why is my text missing once I set the desired Highlight color?

Comment: Looks to me like the `style` gets evaluated either or. So when you have the mouse pointer over the control, it displays an empty control (as in the template setter isn't applied) and just sets the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "#3399ff" try with "#663399ff". Adding opacity will make colors transparent and they wont cover your text.
Also you may find this useful http://yolijn.com/convert-rgba-to-rgb to  calculate resulting color from background color and transparent color over it.

Answer (score 0):

The Opocity thing did not work for me. This also was not the problem, because I should have then seen some text if even if it was not highlighted. This was not the case. So I had to fiddle for quite a while, whilest not knowing what I'm doing ;-). By replacing:

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2" />
```

with

```
<ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
```

solved the problem for me. Hope this small thing will help someone else.